# How to change Flex 4 Radiobutton selected fontWeight

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4, radio-button, flash-builder

I have been searching around for a while now, and cant find anything.  In Flex, I need to be able to change the fontWeight of a RadioButton that is selected to bold.  So, when a RadioButton is selected, it would call a function in AS3 that would set the fontWeight of that selected RadioButton...

```
valveRadioGroup.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeRadioHandler);

private function changeRadioHandler(event:Event):void {         
    //change this RadioButton's fontWeight to bold
}
```

It would also need to revert back to its normal fontWeight when it is not selected. Does anyone know if this is possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just implement your own `RadioButtonSkin` (make a copy of existing one) and change `Label` declaration there:

```
<s:Label id="labelDisplay" fontWeight.selectedStates="bold"
         textAlign="start"
         verticalAlign="middle"
         maxDisplayedLines="1"
         left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2" />
```

You can apply this skin using CSS or directly with `skinClass` attribute.